# Add one hour to summer dst

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the follow code to get the local time in ms:

```
var dtNow = DateTime.Now;
var time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((dtNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime()).TotalMilliseconds);
long end_time = Convert.ToInt64(time.TotalMilliseconds);
```

The time object indicate to correct hour (11:20:00) but the ms object indicate on 12:20:00, Why its happend and how i can fix it?

Before the summer dst Its works perfecr.

Thanks!

Comment: To avoid issues with local time and time changing (summer/winter) you better have to use UTC time. If you need to work with local time anyway, check [DateTimeOffset structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Check this article : [Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Because your `dtNow = DateTime.Now;` is local and with `(dtNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime())` you're converting the time to local again *.ToLocalTime()*

Try:

```
var dtNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
```